# Thymeleaf migrating from 2 to 3

Tags: thymeleaf

In Thymeleaf 2.1.6 we had `AbstractSingleAttributeModifierAttrProcessor`. What are the classes I need to use, if we are migrating to Thymeleaf 3.0.6? This class is not there now. I see that there are many improvements done in 3 w.r.t processors - https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/400 and https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/399

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From

> https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/extendingthymeleaf.pdf
>
> ### Special kinds of processors
>
> Although processors can execute on any node in the DOM tree, there are two specific kinds of processors that can
>   benefit from performance improvements inside the Thymeleaf execution engine: 
>   attribute processors
>    and 
>   element
>   processors
>   .
>
> ### Attribute Processors
>
> Those processors (implementations of 
>   IProcessor
>   ) which 
>   getMatcher()
>    method returns a matcher implementing the
>   `org.thymeleaf.processor.IAttributeNameProcessorMatcher` interface
>    are considered 
>   “attribute processors”
>   .
>   Because of the type of matchers they define, these processors are triggered when a DOM element (usually an
>   XML/XHTML/HTML5 tag) contains an attribute with a specific name. For example, most processors in the 
>   Standard
>   Dialects
>    act like this, defining matchers for attributes like `th:text`
>   , `th:each`, `th:if`, etc.
>   For the sake of simplicity, Thymeleaf offers an utility abstract class from which attribute processors can extend: `org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor`
>   . This class already returns as matcher an implementation of
>   `IAttributeNameProcessorMatcher` and makes it easier to create this kind of processors.

According to the PDF's front page, this documentation refers to

> Project version: 3.0.9.RELEASE